# string manipulation command line windows 7

Tags: string, batch-file, command-line, substring

i have this script which i think should work, what i actually want is to remove the quotes at either end of the version number

```
echo  parsed in %1 %2
IF "%1%" == "BUILD_VERSION" (
    echo %2:~1,12%)
```

the results are:

```
S:\Office\Source\Framework\Code>echo  parsed in BUILD_VERSION "13.000.0000"
 parsed in BUILD_VERSION "13.000.0000"

S:\Office\Source\Framework\Code>IF "BUILD_VERSION" == "BUILD_VERSION" (echo "13.
000.0000":~1,12 )
"13.000.0000":~1,12
```

all the string functions I have tried do the same.
i got my example to crib from here (which I have only just realised isn't stackoverflow)
https://superuser.com/questions/228794/how-to-extract-part-of-a-string-in-windows-batch-file

Comment: removing the quotes from a parameter is very easy. Try: `echo %~2`

Comment: There is no DOS in Windows 7 (or in several versions prior to it), which means you can't possibly be using DOS (or you're not using Windows 7). Either way, your title or tags are wrong.

Comment: The command line window, what is the scripting language used there called, always called it dos sorry.

Comment: Stephen, will try that when i get back to work after the weekend, was it the : that was causing the string manipulation functions not to work?

Comment: yes, the `:`-trick works only for variables (`%var%`), not for parameters (`%1`) or `for`variables (`%%i`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing the value of a parameter always without double quotes independent on parameter was passed to batch file with or without double quotes is possible with `~` between `%` and the parameter number as [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) wrote in first comment.

```
@echo parsed in %~1 %~2
```

This single line in batch file called with `BUILD_VERSION "13.000.0000"` results in the output

```
parsed in BUILD_VERSION 13.000.0000
```

Help of command **FOR** output in a command prompt window after entering either `for /?` or `help for` contains the explanation for this replacement and others on referencing either a parameter of a batch file or a variable of command **FOR**.

See help of command **SET** displayed on entering `set /?` or `help set` in a command prompt window to get explained what can be used for modifying the value of an environment variable. But those modifiers cannot be used on batch parameters or variables of command **FOR** as [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) wrote in his second comment.

Comment: I didn't even expect there to be any help, so didn't look for it, am plesantly suprised